# Admob mediation open bidding on Facebook Audience Network, Ad not loading

Tags: android, admob, facebook-audience-network

I was trying to implement Facebook Audience Network on Admob mediation. I couldn't load bidding ad from Admob, but waterfall ad is loading.

This is what i get in test suit.

It always gives : `I/Ads: Ad failed to load : 3` in console. which means no ad to serve now. But it past more than 24 hours didn't get any ad. It is unusual for bidding to not serve any ads.

Did i miss anything.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are your test ads loading correctly??

Comment: yes.. and FB waterfall ads are loaded successfully...

Comment: FB is closing its waterfall ads. You have to move to open bidding.

Comment: thats what i'm trying to do.

Comment: If your test ads are loading fine, then there is nothing you have to worry about. Fb or Admob will start loading, when they would get the right ads for you.

Comment: In production build, no ad is there...

Answer (score 0):

After checking result of AdMob Test suite and Test Ad you are good to go.

Error code "3" means No Fill.

FAN SDK provides fill when below 2 cases are fulfilled.

1. facebook app must be installed on device or facebook ID is logged in on chrome app.
2. Your APK must be Installed from the play store.

If both the case is true then you should check the floor price on facebook business manager. For testing remove the floor prices.

Comment: FB app is there and loged in chrome .
 "Your APK must be Installed from the play store." - does signed apk counts?

Comment: No, live ads only comes when user actually downloaded your app from play store.

Comment: it has already 900k downloads

Comment: Are your admob ads loading??

Comment: Ok Have you publish the app with open bidding code on play store.?
I mean to say that your testing apk where you are checking/testing it should be installed from play store.

Comment: As far as i know, installed from play store and signed apk are same.

Comment: yes It is same. but facebook sdk check for installer when it fills the ads.
context.packageManager.getInstallerPackageName(context.packageName).equals(
"com.android.vending")

Comment: Do you have any valid link to verify that. Its not my app, i can't test it like that.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/optimization/best-practices/an-policy#other

Audience Network is only available to apps offered in Apple iTunes or Google Play, unless you have our prior written approval.

Comment: Also If you logged in with Main Facebook/developer  account then you can see ads from non-playstore builds.

Comment: I'm added as developer, I did see ad before on signed apk installs.

Comment: ok then ad should come if you signed in on facebook app with dev account.

Answer (score 0):

Just add your device as test device in FAB account or add it programmatically like:

```
AdsSetting.addTestdevice("your device id")
```

Something like that.